Next.js redirect without startTransition does not work
I'm relatively new to both SSR & the useTransition react hook.
Can someone please explain why an onClick callback as defined below only works inside a startTransition?
'use client';

const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

const _skipAction = useCallback((e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // This works
    startTransition(async () => {
      redirect('/');
    });

    // This doesn't work - click event is ignored
    // redirect('/');
  }, []);


After playing around with next.js for a while, I have gotten some further clarity on things. There still has to be a better solution but since routing in next.js is handled on the server side, setTransition allows the app to switch context when inside a client component.
